# WPF,C# I don't understand, Ticker Moving From "From" to"To"

Tags: c#, wpf, ticker

in Code

```
private void TickerGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double height = TickerCanvas.ActualHeight - TextBoxMarquee.ActualHeight;
    TextBoxMarquee.Margin = new Thickness(0, height / 2, 0, 0);
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -TextBoxMarquee.ActualWidth; // -277
    doubleAnimation.To = TickerCanvas.ActualWidth; //524
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    TextBoxMarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```

in Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="TickerGrid" Grid.Row="2" Loaded="TickerGrid_Loaded" Background="#2B2F3B" >
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="TickerCanvas" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock ClipToBounds="True" Name="TextBoxMarquee" Background="#2B2F3B">
            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#55CFE3" FontSize="14" Text="This is WPF Ticker Title." />
                <Run FontSize="13" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Text="This is Content text." />
            </TextBlock.Inlines>
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image: This Ticker Picture]

I did make a ticker, but I do not understand the principle that Canvas moves from "From" to "To".

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is it you are confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBoxMarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);` is the confusing part.

It does NOT animate the Canvas. It animates the Right Property of the textblock.

Canvas.RightProperty is just an identifier of the property, not a reference to the object that has the property. The call to BeginAnimation is on the TextBoxMarquee so the Right property of the TextBox will be animated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a marquee animation then I'd use two textblocks.

You will find a working sample linked from the article here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Marquee

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-User-Notification-MVVM-98940828

The sample has a grid, which will expand to fit the width of whatever container it's in.

There is a canvas in this.

A Canvas does not clip it's content if it's outside of the canvas bounds.

That canvas allows one textblock to be positioned offscreen to the right of the panel and another left of the panel.

The grid is then animated left to right.

Storyboard:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- "To" of this is set in code because of the window resizing -->
    <Storyboard x:Key="SBmarquee">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0"  
                         Duration="00:00:8"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="Xmarquee" 
                         RepeatBehavior="3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                         Storyboard.TargetName="MarqueeContainer" 
                         To="1"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                         Storyboard.TargetName="MarqueeContainer" 
                         BeginTime="0:0:20"
                         Duration="0:0:4" To="0"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Grid:

```
    <Grid x:Name="MarqueeContainer" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Xmarquee" X="0"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas Height="24" 
            TextBlock.Foreground="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarqueeMessage, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Canvas.Left="0">
                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SBmarquee}" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </TextBlock.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarqueeMessage}"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

As the leftmost textblock moves off the display, the rightmost appears.

Code in Window_ContentRendered and  Window_SizeChanged is used to calculate what the current width of the window is.

```
    private Storyboard SBMarquee;
    private DoubleAnimation XAnimation;
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SBMarquee = this.Resources["SBmarquee"] as Storyboard;
        XAnimation = SBMarquee.Children[0] as DoubleAnimation;
        XAnimation.To = MarqueeContainer.ActualWidth * -1;
        this.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        XAnimation.To = MarqueeContainer.ActualWidth * -1;
        MarqueeContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        SBMarquee.Begin();
        MarqueeContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

The animation is stopped and re-started by telling it to begin again. This is the simplest way to avoid weirdness as the user resizes.

I hope that's clear.